# Moving data from Dynamo to Redshift in real-time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift

I want to move data from our dynamo DB to redshift, but I want to do this is real time as we are currently under a migration and still using the dynamo DB, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I did a bit of research and found the following possible solutions

- AWS Data pipelines
- AWS Glue - heard it is not the greatest at times
- Amazon Kinesis
- AWS Lambda
- Amazon DynamoDB Streams
- AWS DMS

I don't have to much experience in some of those services, so any help of suggestions would be appreciated greatly

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/streamsmain.html). There are two options:

1. [Kinesis Data Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/kds.html) (recommended by AWS, probably best for high velocity data changes)
2. [Lambda Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) (easier, good enough for low velocity changes)

When changes occur, the changes are added to the stream which either Kinesis or a triggered lambda function can access. In the case of lambda, the events are stored in the triggering `event` object. You can then use the lamdba function to move your data to `RedShift`.